# Sharing location on google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-location

I'm new to android Location API and Maps. I was thinking about making an application which can be used to share location of friends and locate them on Google Maps. There are many kinds of apps which exists in the market like **Find My Friends** by Apple [FindMyFriends](https://www.apple.com/apps/find-my-friends)

The only way which I thought to spot my friends on google maps was to create a database, put their profile information (like name,phone,email-id) and retrieve it back. Is there any other way which is much better than the way I proposed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had worked on similar projects. I hope my brief info would be helpful to you. You certainly do have to create database and it should be on the server which is accesed by API.

For server part what  you need is an **REST API** which can be created on php , jsp or other.  Api handles the request and response data using json(may be other too).

In android its better to use  **google map api v2** , and use **LocationManager** or **LocationClient** classes for getting current location in longitude and latitude format  and update it to database by sending request to Api.